# Unable to compare part of a std_logic_vector to a constant

Tags: vhdl

So in VHDL, I have a signal that's a std_logic_vector called A (let's say it's 32 bits). I want to look at bits 31...28 of A, check if it's 0001, and then do something if it is. So I have an if statement set up like this:

```
if (A(3 downto 0) = "0001") then:
    --do something
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting errors related it, but I'm not being told exactly what the error is:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "/home/csmajs/jchio001/Desktop/bcd_alu/bcd_alu.vhd" Line 104: Syntax error near "when".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "/home/csmajs/jchio001/Desktop/bcd_alu/bcd_alu.vhd" Line 108: Syntax error near "when".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "/home/csmajs/jchio001/Desktop/bcd_alu/bcd_alu.vhd" Line 110: Syntax error near "case".
```

(I have the if statement in a case statement)
As you can see, I'm being told the there's an error with the code around it, rather than being told that there's an error with this if statement. If I remove the if statement from my code, everything's fine, so I know that it's the if statement that's invalid. So what's wrong with this if statement?

Full code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity my_bcd_alu is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           Opcode : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           Result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(35 downto 0);
           Carry_out : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Overflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Zero : out  STD_LOGIC);
end my_bcd_alu;

architecture Behavioral of my_bcd_alu is
signal temp: std_logic_vector(35 downto 0);
signal sig_A: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal sig_B: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
Variable tempA: INTEGER;
Variable tempB: INTEGER;
Variable decA: INTEGER;
Variable decB: INTEGER;
begin
process(A, B, Opcode, temp, sig_A, sig_B)
begin
    decA := 0;
    decB := 0;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(3 downto 0)));
    decA := decA + tempA;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(7 downto 4)));
    decA := decA + tempA;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(11 downto 8)));
    decA := decA + tempA;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(15 downto 12)));
    decA := decA + tempA;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(19 downto 16)));
    decA := decA + tempA;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(23 downto 20)));
    decA := decA + tempA;
    tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(27 downto 24)));
    decA := decA + tempA;           

    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(3 downto 0)));
    decB := decB + tempB;
    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(7 downto 4)));
    decB := decB + tempB;
    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(11 downto 8)));
    decA := decB + tempB;
    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(15 downto 12)));
    decB := decB + tempB;
    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(19 downto 16)));
    decB := decB + tempB;
    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(23 downto 20)));
    decB := decB + tempB;
    tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(27 downto 24)));
    decB := decB + tempB;           
    case Opcode is
        when "1000" =>          
            tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(31 downto 28)));
            decA := decA + tempA;
            tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(31 downto 28)));
            decB := decB + tempB;
            temp <= std_logic_vector(TO_UNSIGNED(decA + decB, 35));
        when "1001" =>
            tempA := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A(31 downto 28)));
            decA := decA + tempA;
            tempB := TO_INTEGER(unsigned(B(31 downto 28)));
            decB := decB + tempB;                   
            temp <= std_logic_vector(TO_UNSIGNED(decA - decB, 35));
        when "1100" =>
            sig_A <= std_logic_vector(TO_SIGNED(tempA, 32));            
            if (A(31 downto 28) = "0001") then --ERRORS HERE
                sig_A <= std_logic_vector(TO_SIGNED(tempA, 32));            
                sig_A <= NOT(sig_A);
            end if;
        when "1101" =>          
            if (A(31 downto 28) = "0001") then
                sig_A <= std_logic_vector(TO_SIGNED(tempA - 1, 32));            
                sig_A <= NOT(sig_A);
            end if;
        when others =>
            temp <= "0000"&A;
    end case;

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

EDIT: Adding end if removed the errors, but now I get:

```
Line 48: Variable outside of subprogram or process must be 'shared'
```

Comment: The only things wrong with the posted snippet are the (harmless) unnecessary parentheses and the (not harmless) spurious colon. Oh, and the mismatch between the bitslice you want to check (31 downto 28) and that you actually check (3 downto 0). Post a larger excerpt so we can see what the problem is. (Wild guess : missing `end if;` )

Comment: I'll edit with the full code

Comment: You should declare your variables between `process()` and `begin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `variable`s in the architecture's declaration part:

```
architecture Behavioral of my_bcd_alu is
    signal temp: std_logic_vector(35 downto 0);
    signal sig_A: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal sig_B: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    Variable tempA: INTEGER; -- Invalid
    Variable tempB: INTEGER; -- Invalid
    Variable decA: INTEGER;  -- Invalid
    Variable decB: INTEGER;  -- Invalid
begin
```

Either use signal instead (and modify your logic appropriately), or put the `variable` inside the `process` declarations:

```
process(A, B, Opcode, temp, sig_A, sig_B)
    Variable tempA: INTEGER;
    Variable tempB: INTEGER;
    Variable decA: INTEGER;
    Variable decB: INTEGER;
begin
```

As a free bonus, I'll give you some advice on your code, that you really should heed!

- Do not use unconstrained integers. By the VHDL standard, they are 32 bits signed. The synthesis tool **may** optimized them to a smaller size, but you shouldn't count on it. Figure the max values yourself, and use `integer range min to max` to ensure no bigger than necessary usage.
- In a combinational process (without clock, like yours), any output set by that process has to be set in every path through the process. For instance, `sigA` has no value when `Opcode` is "1000" or "1001", and `temp` is not set in the other two cases. Failure to set them in every path result in a latch, which will cause undesirable problem in your implementation. You do not have to do this for variables, as long as you do not rely on the variables keeping it's value between process' executions.